# User Input not working with keyboard.nextLine() and String (Java)

Tags: java

I recently started learning java during my spare time. So to practice, I'm making a program that takes a temperature (Celsius or Fahrenheit) and converts it to the opposite. I've already imported the keyboard scanner.

```
    int temp;
    String opposite, type;
    double product;

    System.out.print("Please enter a temperature: ");
    temp = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Was that in Celsius or Fahrenheit?");
    System.out.print("(Enter 'C' for Celsius and 'F' for Fahrenheit) ");
    type = keyboard.nextLine();

    if (type == "C") // Only irrelevant temp conversion code left so I'm leaving it out
```

I'm new to the String and `nextLine` stuff and the program just skips over the user input section where you enter either C or F. Would someone explain what I can do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, see [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you code Change `nextLine();` to `next();` and it will work.

```
System.out.println("Was that in Celsius or Fahrenheit?");
    System.out.print("(Enter 'C' for Celsius and 'F' for Fahrenheit) ");
    type = keyboard.next();
```

to get an idea for you to what happened was this:

> - nextLine(): Advances this **scanner past the current line** and    **returns the input that was skipped.**
> - next(): Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

Also like the many of the answers says use `equals()` instead of using `==`

The `==` checks only the references to the object are equal. `.equal()` compares string.

Read more [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Answer (score 0):

`.nextInt()` does not read the end of line character `"\n"`.

You need to put a `keyboard.nextLine()` after the `.nextInt()` and then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Never use `Scanner#nextLine` after `Scanner#nextInt`. Whenever you hit enter button after `Scanner#nextInt` than it will skip the `Scanner#nextLine` command. So,
Change from

```
 int temp = keyboard.nextInt();
```

to

```
 int temp = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, use `type.equals("C")` instead of `if (type == "C")`, the later one is comparing the reference of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
  keyboard.nextLine();
```

After

```
  temp = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Because nextInt() doesn't consume the `\n` character.

Also, compare `Strings` with `.equals();` not `==`

```
if(type.equals("C"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Scanner Class:

```
int temp;
java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
String opposite, type;
double product;

System.out.print("Please enter a temperature: ");
temp = s.nextInt();

System.out.println("Was that in Celsius or Fahrenheit?");
System.out.print("(Enter 'C' for Celsius and 'F' for Fahrenheit) ");
type = s.nextLine();

if (type.equals("C")){
do something
}
else{
do something
}
```

For More Input references:

[Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

[BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

[String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) is a wonderful comparison on how to compare strings in java.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `keyboard.next()` instead of `nextLine()`
and as

> user1770155

mentioned to compare two strings you should use `.equals()`
and what I would do since you're comparing to an upper letter "C" is

```
 type = keyboard.next().toUpperCase();



if (type.equals("C"))
```