# Trying to get filename by user input, and print message if the say "no" to wanting to write to a file

Tags: java, filewriter

So, I'm trying to have the user write a filename if they want to write to a file, and write "Thanks for playing" in the Console id they don't want to write to a file.

However, no matter if I type in "yes" or "no", it will either not give the file prompt, or goes into an infinite loop with the names and ages printed, depending on where I put it.

I'll post the code in question below.

```
    String answer2;
    String write;
    String fileName;
    
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> ages = new ArrayList<>();


    // If I put it here, it will do a infinite loop of the names and ages inputted.
    // Prompt the user if they want to write to a file.
    System.out.println("Do you want to write to a file? ");
    answer2 = keyboard.nextLine();

    do
    {
     // If I put it here, it will continue to ask me the question infinitely.
              // Prompt the user if they want to write to a file.
              // System.out.println("Do you want to write to a file? ");
              //answer2 = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
    while (answer.equals("no"));

    do
    {
        // Prompt for the filename
        System.out.println("Enter your filename: ");
        fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
        //break;
        
        //PrintWriter outputFile;
        try 
        {
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(fileName);
            
            // Write the name(s) and age(s) to the file
            outputFile.println(names);
            outputFile.println(ages);
            
            outputFile.close();
        } 
        
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // 
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }   
    
    while (answer2.equals("yes"));
    
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
        break;
    }
    
    while (answer2.equals("no"));
    keyboard.close();
```

Comment: do/while loops always run at least once, so even if they type `no`, it'll run once (and will run endlessly if you type 'yes'). Secondly, `nextLine` and `nextAnythingElse` don't work together. Pick one, and never use the other. Most likely you want `.useDelimiter("\\R")` (call that on your scanner), then `.next()` gets a line, `.nextInt()` gets a line and reads it as an int, etc.

Comment: Hi @rzwitserloot
Oh okay, I see. Thanks for letting me know. So, are you saying I need to pick either next or nextline and stick with the one I pick? I just want to make sure that what you were saying, as I initially thought you were using nextAnythingElse as a variable name, but then I realized that I believed that you were using that as a general variable, if that makes sense.

Also, when I put the .useDelimiter("\\R") part on the scanner would that line of code look like this Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\R");?

Comment: Yes, either use `next` / `nextInt` / `nextDouble`, and all the other methods in that vein, but do not use `nextLine` _or_ use none of those and use only `nextLine`. With `scanner.useDelimiter("\\R")` you no longer need `nextLine`. Which is convenient.

Comment: @rzwitserloot
Okay, thanks for letting me know. I apparently still had one next, while the rest were nextLine. So, I changed it to nextLine, and now the names and ages print only when I say no, so thank you so much.

That being said, I still am having problems with the file part, except now instead of printing errors, it will either not give the file prompt, or goes into an infinite loop with the names and ages printed, depending on where I put it. I've updated the code above to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

A `do` / `while` loop does.. well, use a dictionary if you have to. It obviously **loops**. It keeps doing the thing in the brackets until the while clause is no longer true. Your code will continually keep asking.

You want an `if`, not a `do/while` loop here.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice, I really appreciate it. 
I'm a little confused, which loop should I change though?

Comment: Apart from not needing a `do while` (or any kind of loop) because you need an `if` to execute once, not a loop to execute many times, the problem you have is the condition of the loop `answer.equals("no")` never changes because `answer` never changes *inside* the loop. For a loop to terminate, the termination condition must have a way of becoming true.

Comment: Hi @Bohemian
Okay, thanks for the advice, and for dropping by again; I really appreciate it. 
So, what else do I need to do besides changing the do-while loop? Do I need to change the answer.equals("no") part as well?

Comment: At some point you're just asking 'what do I type on my keyboard for my java app to work', and this ceases to be 'developer help' and turns into 'how to spoonfeed a newbie'. Tutorials are much, _much_ more suitable to that job, trust me.