# String out of Range, Help please

Tags: java, string, loops, repeat

I am unsure what to do as I am quite new to Java. I want to repeat this program again but it keeps giving me the error of my string being out of range. How do I approach this?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class LoanReport {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        double loanBalance;
        double interestRate;
        int loanYears;
        String answer;
        char again;
        // boolean again;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

// while(again)
// do{
        System.out.print("Enter the " + "loan amount.");
        loanBalance = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the " + "annual interest rate.");
        interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the " + "years of the loan.");
        loanYears = keyboard.nextInt();

        Amortization am = new Amortization(loanBalance, interestRate, loanYears);

        am.saveReport("LoanAmortization.txt");
        System.out.println("Report saved to " + "the file LoanAmortization.txt.");

        System.out.print("Would you like " + "to run another report? Enter Y for " + "yes or N for no: ");
//answer = keyboard.next(); 
        // again = answer.charAt(0);
//} 
//while(answer == 'Y' || answer  == 'y');
        answer = keyboard.nextLine();
        again = answer.charAt(0);
        if (again == 'N' || again == 'n') {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried doing a boolean method but I'm unsure if I did that correctly.

Comment: If user input empty line, `answer` will be `""`, and `answer.charAt(0)` will out of range

Comment: How do I not allow them to input an empty line?

Answer (score 0):

String out of range error occurs when you are trying to access a position in a string, in this case `answer.charAt(0)`, that does not exist.

`nextLine():` Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.
`next():` Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.
[See more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29641047/9063959)

Try using:

```
answer = keyboard.next()
```

instead of:

```
answer = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Also, use `answer.equals("N")` instead of `if (answer == "N")`, the later one is comparing the reference of the value.

Comment: It runs but it does not repeat the program again when I put "Y"

Comment: Of course it doesn't, you have just told it what to do if they choose "N", which is the option for the program to stop. You need an else if statement or a while loop to keep the application going.

Comment: When doing the else if statement, I am slightly confused. I did
 if (answer == "Y" || answer == "y")
 { this is the part I am confused with, not sure how to loop)
}
else 
{
 system.exit(0)
}

Comment: Put the entire thing in a while loop while(continue) where boolean continue = true initially, and it should keep going until the user hits 'N' and the application stops. Mind you this will keep going untill the user hits 'N' or 'n', any other input will make the app repeat.

Comment: Did it all work out in the end? Don't forget to use equals instead of == as mentioned in my answer as equals is the correct way to compare strings instead of references of values.